# Child ManyToOne relation attribute from parent element always null JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, jpa

I have these classes:

**Compania**

```
@Entity(name = "Compania")
@Table(
    name = "compania"
)
public class Compania {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "compania_sequence",
        sequenceName = "compania_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator = "compania_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
        nullable = false
    )
    private Long id;


    @Column(
        name = "name",
        nullable = false,
        unique = true
    )
    private String name;

    @Column(
        name = "dominio",
        nullable = true
    )
    private String dominio;

    @Column(
        name = "altas"
    )
    private String altas;

    @Column(
        name = "bajas"
    )
    private String bajas;

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Office> office;
```

And on the other hand I have this one:

**Office**

```
@Entity(name = "Office")
@Table(name = "office")
public class Office {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "office_sequence",
        sequenceName = "office_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "office_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
        nullable = false
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(
        name = "idRef",
        nullable = false
    )
    private int idRef;

    @Column(
        name = "title",
        nullable = false
    )
    private String title;

    @Column(
        name = "name"
    )
    private String name;
    @Column(
        name = "path"
    )
    private String path;

    @ManyToOne
    private Compania compania;
```

So my problem is that when I check the office objects I get this with a GET method:

```
{
        "idRef": 0,
        "title": "titulo1",
        "name": "office 1",
        "path": "path_office",
        "compania": null
    }
```

As you can see compania appears as null, so this is giving me a lot of headaches as I'm not being able for example to do a query like this one, where I try to get the offices related to a compania by id and their titles:

```
@Query("select o from Office o where o.compania.id = :companiaId and lower(o.title) like lower(concat('%', :title, '%') ) ")
    List<Office> getChilds(@Param("companiaId") Long companiaId, @Param("title")String title);
```

How could I solve this problem? Till now I've been able to do a lot of requests using the Compania class as the main Entity, using the CompaniaService, CompaniaRepository... etc.

However, now that I need to work exclusively with Office I can't do it. Of course, for the query I'd like to do, I could the list of offices from the compania and then iterate them to store them in a list and then return that list, but I feel that is not the right way to do it.

Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Is there any different approach to this problem?

Edit. For saving entities I create a Compania, that I pass as JSON through a POST method, and then I save it using the companiaService.save(compania) like this:

```
public void postCompania(Compania compania) {
        if (compania.getId() != null) {
            if (companiaRepository.existsById(compania.getId())) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Compañia con id " + compania.getId() + " ya existe"
                );
            }
        }

        companiaRepository.save(compania);
        System.out.println(compania);
    }
```

I changed the OneToMany relationship in Compania to make it look like this:

```
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "compania",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Office> office;
```

To create the fk the app does this:

```
alter table office 
       add constraint FKj87ris6ubebpw5t7fkmy5i9bx 
       foreign key (compania_id) 
       references compania
```

Comment: I don't full understand your problem but spotted a wrong mapping:  @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator = "compania_sequence"
    ) Should be GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
@OneToMany(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
```

And this

```
@ManyToOne
private Compania compania;
```

With this mapping those two relationships are **unrelated**!

You have to add the mappedBy attribute to indicate that this is a related relationship:

```
@OneToMany(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    orphanRemoval = true,
    mappedBy = "compania"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still getting the null problem. :S. Should I delete something? Everytime I save a Compania I'm still getting the attribute of the ManyToOne compania as null.. :S

Comment: Please show how you save the entities. And do you have the foreign key set in the database?

Comment: @Varox You have to fetch eagerly

Comment: @SirHawrk Why? If the relationship wasn't initialized there would be a LazyInitializationException

Comment: I tried, to change to fetch EAGER and that didn't work neither. I've updated the post with more info :S Thank you very much

Comment: And how do you save the office?